# Sharepoint Online Choice Column resets to '1' after form submitted, no matter what number's actually put in

Tags: sharepoint-online

This is super weird because firstly, no changes were made anywhere, the behaviour just randomly started two weeks ago. Secondly, the number only *displays* as '1', it is still *registered* as the correct number. I can even briefly see the correct number when viewing the list on the o365 site just after form submission, before it suddenly changes to '1'. Form submission on this list also triggers a flow that sends that field in an approval email. When the email arrives, the number is the correct one that the user entered. The list is a standard list.

Has anyone encountered anything similar before? Thanks!

Dan

Comment: Are you resetting the value of this choice column in your flow? please check it once.

Comment: Hey Ganesh, thanks for your reply. I checked the flow but it doesn't reset the value.